# Find the largest sequence in a given array of numbers

Tags: java

program to find largest sequence in a given list of numbers

INPUT = [1,2,3,2,4,5,6,7,8,1,0,4,5,6]
Expected Result: [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

```
 package CaseStudy;
    import java.util.Arrays;



    public class LargestSequence {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            int[] array = {1,2,3,2,4,5,6,7,8,1,0,4,5,6};
            int count=0;
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++) {
                if (array[i+1]==(array[i])+1)
                {
                    count++;
                    System.out.print (array[i]);    

                }

        }

     }
    }
```

I tried and I am not able to get the desired output.

Comment: You'd want the top 5 largest numbers?

Comment: You get a wrong result because you don't reset the counter. You just add `1` every time the next element fits your condition. But as soon as the condition doesn't fit anymore you need to reset the counter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset the count to zero in the event that the sequence gets broken.  The logic in the solution below is that for each subsequent in-sequence number, we increment the count by 1 (the count starts at one for each new sequence), and also we append the current digit to a CSV string, to be printed later after the algorithm has run on the full string of numbers.

```
int[] array = {1,2,3,2,4,5,6,7,8,1,0,4,5,6};
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("" + array[0]);
String sequence = "";
int count = 1;
int maxCount = 1;

for (int i=1; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] == array[i-1] + 1) {
        count++;
        sb.append(",").append(array[i]);
    }
    if (array[i] != array[i-1] + 1 || i == array.length - 1) {
        if (count > maxCount) {
            maxCount = count;
            sequence = sb.toString();
        }
        count = 1;
        sb = new StringBuilder("" + array[i]);
    }
}

System.out.println("The longest sequence was " + sequence + ", with a length of: " + maxCount);
```

### Demo

This prints:

```
The longest sequence was 4,5,6,7,8, with a length of: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do with java-stream,

```
int[] array = {1,2,3,2,4,5,6,7,8,1,0,4,5,6};

Arrays.stream(array).distinct(). //covert array to stream and get distinct elements
        .boxed()                 // get Integer stream Stream<Integer>
        .sorted()                // sort the array
        .skip(Arrays.stream(array).distinct().count()-5) //last 5 elements PS. not a right way for larger arrays
        .forEach(System.out::println);  // print each element
```

**EDIT**: I misunderstood the question. You can get largest sequence as below,

```
int[] a = {1,2,3,2,4,5,6,7,8,1,0,4,5,6};
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(a[0]+""); //first char
int count = 0;

for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i] > a[i - 1]) {
        count++;
        sb.append(a[i]);
    } else {
        count = 0;
        sb.append(" ");    // add spearator for each sequesnce
    }
}
String largestSeq = Arrays.stream(sb.toString().split(" ")) //get the largese seq based on lenght
        .max(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length))
        .get();
```

Comment: Can you please explain this answer??

Comment: added comments.

Comment: This fails to find the correct substring should the matching length be anything but 5.

Comment: The question was specific to the top 5 largest numbers. It can be replaced with n.

Comment: No, that wasn't the requirement.  The requirement was to find the longest continuous subsequence of numbers, of any arbitrary length.  You don't know what the value of `n` is before calling your stream.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I misunderstood the question. Updated the answer.